# What is a 2 Ball CPU Cooler?

Tags: cpu-cooler

When looking through CPU fans and heatsinks at [newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&DEPA=0&Order=BESTMATCH&Description=ball%20cpu%20cooler&x=0&y=0), I see some that are "2 ball coolers" and others are "1 ball coolers".  What is a 2 ball CPU cooler? How is it superior to a 1 ball?

Answer (score 2):

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_fan):

> "Though generally more expensive, ball bearing fans do not suffer the
>   same orientation limitations as sleeve bearing fans, are more durable
>   especially at higher temperatures, and are quieter than sleeve bearing
>   fans at higher rotation speeds. The lifespan of a ball bearing fan may
>   be around 63,000 hours at 50 °C"

A 2 ball fan simply means that the sleeve uses 2 ball bearings. It is possible (and usually better) for a bearing to use more than 2 balls, but I have yet to see a computer fan use more than 2 ball bearings.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is a reference to the number of (ball) bearings that the fan has. Bearings are a reliable/durable way of mounting a shaft (i.e. the fan motor) and arguably two may reduce wear/improve durability/reduce noise - I would question the necessity for that degree of excess for a simple fan though.